# Errors in Python AI

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I am currently programming an Artificial Intelligence in Python, with some basic code from ELIZA. I will improve on the code once I get it working. My problem is that when I run the program and enter a query to the computer, there is no response. My code is below.

```
import string

# OSWALD v1.0

switch = [
["I need \(.*\)",
[   "Why do you need %1?",
    "Would it REALLY help you to get %1?",
    "Are you sure you need %1?"]]
 #There is more code with responses.
   ]

gPats = {
"am"    : "are",
"was"   : "were",
"i" : "you",
"i'd"   : "you would",
"i've"  : "you have",
"i'll"  : "you will",
"my"    : "your",
"are"   : "am",
"you've": "I have",
"you'll": "I will",
"your"  : "my",
    "yours" : "mine",
"you"   : "me",
"me"    : "you",
    }
s = input
gKeys = map(lambda x:regex.compile(x[0]),gPats)
gValues = map(lambda x:x[1],gPats)

print ("Hello, mortal. My name is Oswald. What would you like to talk about?")

while s == input:
try: s = input(">")

def translate(str,dict):
words = string.split(string.lower(str))
keys = dict.keys();
for i in range(0,len(words)):
    if words[i] in keys:
        words[i] = dict[words[i]]
return print(switch)

def respond(str,keys,values):
for i in range(0,len(keys)):
    if input == input:
        respnum = whrandom.randint(0,len(values[word])-1)
        resp = values[i][respnum]
        pos = string.find(resp,'%')
        print(string.find(resp,'%'))
        while pos > -1:
            num = string.atoi(resp[pos+1:pos+2])
            resp = resp[:pos] + \
                translate(keys[i].group(num),gReflections) + \
                resp[pos+2:]
            pos = string.find(resp,'%')
        if resp[-2:] == '?.': resp = resp[:-2] + '.'
        if resp[-2:] == '??': resp = resp[:-2] + '?'
        print(string.find(resp,'%'))
```

Comment: If I were you I would wonder if all the code in the example is strictly neccessary....

Comment: Okay. thanks. Sorry about that. Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: Yeah, you may want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question.

Comment: Thank you. This is my first post and I appreciate both of your help.

Comment: at first glance: might not have to be `input == input`, but `input == input()`?

Comment: Thanks Pascal, I just tried that but now on the "def translate" segment it's saying that I have "inconsistent use of indentation"

Comment: You do `s == input`... I'm supposing you want to run the input function, that'd be `input()`

Comment: Try this... whenever you write a "`:`" (if, for, try, while etc), add 4 spaces to the beginning of the line.

Comment: What does "Unexpected EOF while parsing" mean?

Comment: I'd like to warn you, there are a million things wrong in that script... it's not going to run anytime soon. It mostly reminds me of those "find the 7 odd things" when comparing 2 pictures.

Comment: Try starting with some python tutorial, e.g. codeacademy.